# how to sort array of dates per day of the months using table builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of dates which I want to sort per day of the months

```
slots = [Fri, 19 Sep 2014 08:00:00 UTC +00:00, Fri, 19 Sep 2014 08:30:00 UTC +00:00, Fri, 19 Sep 2014 09:00:00 UTC +00:00, Fri, 19 Sep 2014 09:30:00 UTC +00:00]

<%= debug @labor_slots %>
- 2014-09-19 08:00:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 08:30:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 09:00:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 09:30:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 10:00:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 10:30:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 11:00:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 11:30:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 12:00:00.000000000 Z
- 2014-09-19 12:30:00.000000000 Z
```

I'm trying to implement the following example from [**table_builder gem**](https://github.com/watu/table_builder):

```
<%= calendar_for(@tasks) do |t| %>
  <%= t.day do |day, tasks| %>
    <% if tasks.nil? %>
      <%= day.cweek %>
    <% else %>
      <%= day.day %>
      <% tasks.each do |task| %>
        <%= h(task.name) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The documentation of the gem do not offer much details, is it possible to modify this block to use it with my slots array?

Comment: Are you sure about that array? Check it in `irb`.

Comment: That's probably how it looks with `inspect`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I modified the array.